# Why bootstrap modal displays the page behind it instead of its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I got a bootstrap modal to display the new session user form with Devise gem (in Ruby on Rails). The modal works fine in the root path, however in any other path it's a mess. All the content and the header of the modal is replaced by the content of the page that is behind it.

The code is simple, in my *_header.html.erb* I got

`<%= link_to "Ingresar", nil, 'data-toggle':"modal", 'data-target':"#modal-ingresar" %>`

...which toggles the modal. At the end of the *_header.html.erb* I defined the modal like this:

```
     <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-ingresar" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="false">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ingresar</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

<%= render '/layouts/newSession' %>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In */layouts/newSession* I have the form for devise (bunch of code not needed but if you want to take a look here it is: https://github.com/juanmanuelramallo/CouchInn/commit/50230ec5edbb61f9569c26a2327cd72e05815deb )

See these photos:
[image: This one is fine]

This one is fine, but two seconds later this happens:

[image: This modal is showing me the page not the content of the modal]